# What's the simplest Firefox extension for turning proxy usage on and off?

Tags: firefox, proxy, firefox-extensions

There are numerous proxy-related extensions for Mozilla Firefox but all of the seem too bloat for me. I don't need proxy lists management etc. All I need is a status bar button to turn proxy usage on/off (I need this frequently and don't want to use settings window (nor any menus)). Know of such one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [**QuickProxy**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/quickproxy/):

> Statusbar button to turn the proxy on and off with a single click.

[image: 1] [image: 2]